# string как параметр функции

Tags: c++, visual-studio, строки, функции

Здравствуйте. Надо передать методу класса параметр типа данных string.
Имеется определение в файле DoubleVector.cpp

```
void CDoubleVector::saveResult(std::string FileName){}
```

Также в заголовочном файле DoubleVector.h

```
void saveResult(string FileName);
```

Так вот. Не работает.

> Ошибка    C2061   синтаксическая ошибка: идентификатор "string"   c:\users\alexey\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\oop_labwork4\oop_labwork4\doublevector.h  23

Если изменить string на std::string в заголовочном файле, то лучше не становится(что вполне логично) и выдает ошибку:

> Ошибка    C2039   string: не является членом "std"    c:\users\alexey\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\oop_labwork4\oop_labwork4\doublevector.h  23

Так как можно нормально передать string в параметр?

Comment: Тупой вопрос: `#include <string>` писать не пробовали?

Comment: @Harry , как глупо это не звучит, я это не правильно написал. Вместо string устаревшее string.h напечатал. Теперь вроде всё нормально работает. Спасибо.

Comment: Ну, тогда оформляю как ответ :)

Comment: Хорошо. Ещё раз спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не путайте

```
#include <string>
```

и

```
#include <string.h>
```